# Find existing session

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, session

I have this method in my rails app:

```
def find_or_create_session(fbid)
    @sessions = Session.all
    if @sessions.find_by facebook_id: fbid
      @session = @sessions.find_by facebook_id: fbid
      if ((Time.now - @session.last_exchange).fdiv(60)).to_i > 5
        @session = Session.create(facebook_id: fbid, context: {})
      end
    else
       @session = Session.create(facebook_id: fbid, context: {})
    end
    @session
end
```

It retrieves all the `Session`s, and tries to find one with a given `facebook_id`. If there is one, it checks if it's a recent one (`last_exchange` was less than 5 minutes ago). If it's not, it creates a new one.

If it can't find a `session` for this `facebook_id`, it will create one.

This is pretty easy, but it seems to be a lot of if/else for such a straightforward thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- `@session`: A method called `find_or_create_session` should not change the state of instance variables.
- `@sessions.find_by facebook_id: fbid` is written twice. Use variables to avoid repetition. Also, the consensus in the Ruby community is to always write parens (except for DSL-like code).
- `Time.now - @session.last_exchange`: You can perform that check in the  SQL query.
- Your method is basically doing `find_or_create_session = existing_session || new_session`, let the code mimic it.

I'd write:

```
def find_or_create_session(fbid, max_age: 5.minutes)
  Session.find_by(["facebook_id = ? AND last_exchange >= ?", fbid, max_age.ago]) ||
    Session.create(facebook_id: fbid, context: {})
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is equivalent:

```
def find_or_create_session(fbid)
  if (@session = Session.find_by facebook_id: fbid) &&
     (Time.zone.now - @session.last_exchange).fdiv(60).to_i <= 5
    @session
  else
    @session = Session.create(facebook_id: fbid, context: {})
  end
end
```

Some notes:

- No need for an `@sessions` variable unless you'll be using it in the
  views
- Always [use](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Rails/TimeZone) `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.zone`